# Aligning CSS objects above <hr> tags

Tags: html, css

Here's my code for my small project (I'm very new to this):

```css
body {
  background-color: #242424;
}

.page-wrap {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 98vh;
}

.buildings-wrap {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: middle;
}

.rectangle {
  height: 650px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 215px;
}

.add_btn {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: lightcyan;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: 900;
  position: fixed;
  top: 85%;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrap">
  <div class="buildings-wrap">
    <br/>
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <hr style="position: fixed;top: 80%;color: white;width: 84%;" />
    <button class="add_btn">+</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's what it looks like. The arrow show where I would like them to be.

I can't figure out how to do this:

[image]

Comment: Do you want all items in the image to be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to align the rectangle above the `hr` tag, you can simply give it a `display` of `block` and a `margin` of `auto`. This will center the rectangle relative to the container.

As for aligning the add button to the center while keeping it fixed, you can wrap the button in a `div`, give that `div` a position of `fixed` and a `width` of `100%`. Then give it a display of `flex` and `justify-content` of `center`. This will center align any children that are in the `div`.

Depending on how low you want the add button, you can set the `bottom` property for the newly create div. At the moment I have it at -125px. It's also better to use `bottom` and pixels as the units because the other elements have fixed sizes.

```css
body{
    background-color: #242424;
}
.page-wrap {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 98vh;
}
.buildings-wrap{
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: middle;
}
.rectangle{
    height: 650px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    width: 215px;
    display: block;
    margin:auto;
}
.add_btn{
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: lightcyan;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 100px;
    font-weight: 900;
}

hr{
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrap">
        <div class="buildings-wrap">
            <br/>
            <div style="display: flex; margin: auto;"><div class="rectangle"></div></div>
            <hr/>
            <div style="width: 100%; display:flex; justify-content: center;position: fixed; bottom: -125px; left: 0;"><button class="add_btn">+</button></div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: This is too far up the page - how do I lower it to about 3/4 down the page?

Comment: I added `bottom: -125px` to the `div` containing the button. You can adjust it how you see fit. I also think you should use `bottom` since you're positioning it in relation to the bottom. You should also use `px` since the other elements on the page have pixel sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Please view in full-page view

Hope this helps

```css
body {
  background-color: #242424;
}

.page-wrap {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 98vh;
}

.buildings-wrap {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.rectangle {
  height: 81vh;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 200px;
}

.add_btn {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: lightcyan;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  height: 16vh;
  width: 120px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: fixed;
  top: 84%;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrap">
  <div class="buildings-wrap">
    <br/>
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
    <hr style="position: fixed;top: 80%;color: white;width: 84%;" />
    <button class="add_btn">+</button>
  </div>
</div>
```